# jquery full calendar client side filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, filtering

I am using jquery full calendar and populating it from a json feed. Now i want to do a client side filtering of the events. The way i think i can achieve that is some how first make a local array of events and then use it on the client side to show and hide events. to explain a bit more, i first hard coded an array of events to see the working of the calendar. Then i used the 'clientEvents' to filter the events and when i wanted all the events back, i would simply fetch them from the local source, i.e the hard coded array of events. Can i replicate this some how with my json feed, i.e can i tell the calendar to initiallize an array with this source and then use it to filter my events, until i change the month, and it fetches the events and changes the contents of that array?

Or if there is a better approach of doing this , please tell me, because i cannot do the filtering through ajax calls because due to some reasons its a very expensive call and needs to avoided as much as possible.

Any pointer will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON files to load your events like this

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    eventSources: [    
        // your event source
        {
            url: '/myfeed.php', // this is JSON file
            type: 'POST',
            data: {custom_param1: 'something'},
            error: function() {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },              
        }

        // any other sources...

    ]

});
```

[`REFERENCE`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/#options)

also you want to dynamically adds an event source.

then try with this **[addEventSource](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/addEventSource/)**

```
.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', source );
```

`source` may be an **Array/URL/Function** just as in the events option.
Events will be immediately fetched from this source and placed on the calendar.

Comment: yes i know and my json feed is working well, i now want to filter the events but i dont want to fetch events every time from the database, i.e when i filter events on some criteria, and then i remove the criteria, it should not fetch the events from the database, rather it should just have all the events on the clint side and should use them. if i change my month, only then it should make a call to the json feed and fetch new events.

Comment: thanx a lot for your quick responses :) actually my problem is not about adding events or sources, my problem is that once added, i should be able to filter the events on the client side. I can remove events from the client side events using the 'clienEvents' method but once the filters are removed and i call the refetch events, it is going to make a call to the feed and get events from the database, which what i dont want it do, i want it to keep events on the client side and repopulate from there.

Comment: @khizar : i have just completed same thing in my  recent project: